# how to configure a Content Security Policy in a SecurityConfig class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, spring-security, content-security-policy

In my java/spring-boot application, I have a SecurityConfig class as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final BasicAuthenticationProvider basicAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(BasicAuthenticationProvider basicAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.basicAuthenticationProvider = basicAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .antMatcher(PATH_NAME)
                .httpBasic()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I need to configure a `ContentSecurityPolicy` by using the code `.and().headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'")` within the configure method, but I've tried in the possible places and keep getting errors (e.g. cannot resolve method `.and()` when trying the below code)

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .antMatcher(PATH_NAME)
                .httpBasic()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .and().headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");
    }
```

Would anyone know how to properly do this?

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't have to call `.and()` after `csrf().disable()`, since `disable()` already returns the `HttpSecurity` object that you have to configure.

So something like

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .antMatcher(PATH_NAME)
                .httpBasic()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                // notice that .and() is removed from the next line
                .headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");
    }
```